# Where does だらけ come from?

Tags: etymology

Where does the phrase だらけ come from? I only know だ as a copula and ら as a conditional marker or pluralizing suffix, are either of these at use in this phrase? My dictionary lists it as "implying (negatively) that something is full of".

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is no consensus for the origin of this word.  I've checked a number of resources including 日本国語大辞典 (but the 精選版, not the full edition), 日本文法大辞典, and the other various monolingual dictionaries I have at hand, and none offer an explanation.

Martin offers one theory, courtesy of Ōtsuki, on page 136 of his 1975 *Reference Grammar of Japanese*, where he discusses the etymology of several words including だらけ.  First he notes:

> Where do these words come from?  **Many of those with distinctively voiced initials go back to elements with voiceless initials, having picked up the voicing as part of the well-known compound nigori process**.  The restrictive だけ is from the noun たけ 'length; total quantity', related to たか 'amount, volume' and たか- 'high, tall' (as is たけ 'peak').

He gives a number of other examples that fit this pattern, then discusses だらけ very briefly:

> **The origin of だらけ is problematical; one suggestion (Ōtsuki) has it related to たらたら 'dripping profusely'**.

I don't know if you'll find this information satisfying, but it's all I can dig up at the moment.  Perhaps someone else will have something to add.